# ssh в gitlab на локальный интерфейс

Tags: ssh, gitlab

Есть сервер с поднятым gitlab на нём.

Я хочу пересадить ssh на локальный интерфейс вида 10.x.x.x , чтобы ssh не был доступен из сети интернет.

Если я это сделаю, то ssh в gitlab будет работать?
Спасибо.

Comment: куда «пересадите», там и будет работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если я это сделаю, то ssh в gitlab будет работать?

давайте чуть переформулируем изложенное в вопросе:

1. я закрываю доступ к серверу из внешнего мира по протоколу *ssh*
2. будет ли после этого доступен сервер по протоколу *ssh*?

очевидный ответ: для внешнего мира — конечно, нет.

---

комплекс программ и скриптов, называемый *gitlab*, не содержит (насколько мне известно) реализации ssh-сервера. поэтому словосочетание «ssh в gitlab» не совсем корректно. подключаетесь вы именно к ssh-серверу. и если закрываете к нему доступ из внешнего мира, то доступа и не будет.

Comment: я и хочу, чтобы сервер был недоступен для внешнего мира, только по порту 80, но мне надо, чтобы gitlab был доступен по ssh из вне. вот о чём я. или такое невозможно, если я пересажу ssh "внутрь" ?

Comment: дополнил ответ. да, «такое» невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо, всё понял.